# cTAKES and Thread Safety

Tags: java, ctakes

I am facing issues on cTAKES (An apache project) with respect to thread safety while using the AnalysisEngine and JCAS.

I tried getting resolution regarding the same on the Question/Answer on Apache project but not getting sufficient info. If anyone could guide in resolving the same, would appreciate the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UIMA 3.0.0-alpha02 corrects some threading issues. I can't really answer 'issues' without knowing more about it.

Comment: 3.0.0 official release is now available.